# Twitter API - Creating a Listener Bot using Python and Adhering to guidelines

Tags: python, twitter

**Background** - I am trying to create a twitter bot which listens in real time for certain keywords coming only from certain accounts. I want to then notify myself when this situation occurs. I'm flexible as to how I get notified, but my plan was just to have my application repost or retweet the original tweet that met my criteria and then follow my application from my main account with twitter's built in notification system.

**Problem** - Twitter suspended my account for violations while I was trying to test/build this and won't tell me what the violation was. I'm not a real developer - kind of feeling my way through this, so I'm unsure if there is something in the code that might have led to this.

**Actions Taken** I've emailed them for details several times and tried posting on the twitter developer forums, but they aren't responding to my emails and marked my post as "off-topic" in the forum dedicated to twitter developer rules/guidelines.

**Request** As alluded to above this has mostly been trial and error for me since I'm less than a novice..., I am pasting my code below - I'd like to rule out things I don't really understand that a real developer might be able to spot that might have led to this (to many requests in too short a time, bad coding standard practices - something of that nature).

If someone has experience using the twitter API and their specific developer guidelines (example - post formatting) that would be welcomed but it is not my intent to have people read their guidelines for me - I'm just looking for issues with code performance that might lead someone to want to shut down what I did

Thanks!

**Code**

```
import tweepy
import json
import re

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("Token", "Token")
auth.set_access_token("Token", "Token")


api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
    wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        self.me = api.me()

    def on_status(self, tweet):
        keyword = ["Keyword1", "Keyword2"]
        patterns = [r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s.strip()) for s in keyword]
        there = re.compile('|'.join(patterns))
        if there.search(tweet.text):
            print(f"{tweet.user.name}:{tweet.text}")
        api.update_status(f"{tweet.user.name}:{tweet.text}")

    def on_error(self, status):
        print("Error detected")

tweets_listener = MyStreamListener(api)
stream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, tweets_listener)
stream.filter(follow=['Account 1','Account 2'])
```